# Как написать правильно "пожалуйста при пожалуйста"?

Tags: пунктуация, раздельно-дефис

Не важно, какой контекст, я хочу написать "пожалуйста при пожалуйста". Нужны ли тире на месте пробелов, или так их и оставить? И почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно точно утверждать без контекста, но я думаю, что имеется в виду **"пожалуйста-препожалуйста"**. Пишется через дефис. Пример употребления можете посмотреть [по этой ссылке](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=18oRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDjsSV-K7YAhURblAKHTFuCSM4ChDoAQg-MAU). Через запятую тоже встречается, но реже.